# Efficient way to drop subset of columns using a threshold of row numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 10 million row dataframe like this

```
>>> df.info(show_counts=True)

#   Column  Non-Null Count     Dtype         
---  ------  --------------     -----         
 0   date    10000000 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   cust1   6000647 non-null   float64       
 2   cust2   6001585 non-null   float64       
 3   cust3   6000415 non-null   float64       
 4   cust4   9001290 non-null   float64       
 5   cust5   9000402 non-null   float64       
 6   cust6   9000093 non-null   float64       
 7   cust7   8999538 non-null   float64       
 8   cust8   9000211 non-null   float64       
 9   cust9   9000745 non-null   float64       
 10  cust10  9001119 non-null   float64
```

In the general case, all of the columns contain `NA` values. In this example columns `cust1, cust2, cust3` contain around 40% of `NA` values, 10% for the rest. Column `date` has no missing values, for the sake of testing - the general problem assumes every column can have any number of `NA` values.
I'm looking for an idiomatic/efficient way to drop those `custXX` columns whose rows contain less than 70% (i.e. 7 million) of `non-NA` values.

I'm treating `DataFrame.dropna(axis=1,  thresh=thresh)` as a baseline result, just to see how much time it would take Pandas to clear the whole dataframe.

```
%timeit df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=thresh)

701 ms ± 12.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I can't use the `subset` parameter, because in this case it would affect rows, not columns.
I've tried the following solutions:

1. Split the dataframe into one containing only the `custXX` subset of columns, and the other containing the `data` column. Drop NA columns in the first DF, then merge it with the other one using index:

   > ```
   > def split_merge(df):
   >     date_df = df[['date']]
   >     rest_df = df.drop('date', axis=1)
   >     cleared = rest_df.dropna(thresh=thresh, axis=1)
   >     return date_df.merge(cleared, left_index=True, right_index=True)
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > %timeit split_merge(df)
   >
   > 1.65 s ± 49.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
   > ```
2. Select `custXX` DF subset, for each column count number of non-NA values, select only those columns where `count` is at least 70%, then use those columns to select from original dataframe

   > ```
   > def count_select(df):
   >     nan_cols = df.filter(like='cust').columns
   >     non_na_counts = df[nan_cols].notna().sum()
   >     valid_cols = non_na_counts[non_na_counts >= thresh]
   >     all_cols = pd.concat([pd.Series(0, index=['date']), valid_cols]).index
   >     return df[all_cols]
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > %timeit count_select(df)
   >
   > 1.73 s ± 79.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
   > ```
3. Similar to the previous one, but instead of counting, we drop `NA` values and use all of the resulting columns to select from the original dataframe:

   > ```
   > def select_dropna_select(df):
   >     nan_cols = df.filter(like='cust')
   >     cleared = nan_cols.dropna(axis=1, thresh=thresh).columns
   >     new_cols = ['date', *cleared.values]
   >     return df[new_cols]
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > %timeit select_dropna_select(df)
   >
   > 1.54 s ± 14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
   > ```

The last one is the fastest, but still more than twice slower than the baseline solution (clearing the whole dataframe). Is there an idiomatic way to do it that would achieve similar efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. I would encourage you to perform the `timeit` analysis on this solution and let me know the results.

```
m = df.filter(like='cust').isna().mean() > .3 # True if more than 30% nulls
df.drop(m.index[m], axis=1) # drop the columns
```

Comment: `%timeit filter_na_mean(df)`

`1.27 s ± 135 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

It actually did a bit faster. The *tiny* downside to it is that we need a columns of specific names, but that's something that's easy to sort out.